# Drupal - get $primary_links with nested menus as php array

Tags: php, drupal, menu, themes

I'm trying to get a PHP array that includes a simple nested list of primary_links and their sub-menu items. This seems like a simple task but I can't seem to get a straight answer on how exactly to do it.

From there I would theme it exactly as needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick!

```
menu_tree_all_data('primary-links')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this function? menu_primary_links();